# Is there some way to refer to the previous object in the Pipeline?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

In the following code, is there some way to reference the current object in the second segment from the third segment?

```
`$a = "one", "two", "three"`
`$a | % {$_ -replace "t","x" } | % { $_ }`
```

To explain a little differently, I'd love to be able to use something like `| % { "$_.$_ : $_" }` in the third pipeline segment to get this output:

```
one: one
two: xwo
three: xhree
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the only solution I have found so far. Is there some better alternative?

```
$a = "one", "two", "three"
$a | % { $i = $_; $_ -replace "t","x" } | % { "$i : $_" }
```

output:

```
one : one
two : xwo
three : xhree
```

Comment: `$a | % {  "$_ : $($_ -replace "t","x")" }`

Comment: It's not as pretty as I would have liked, but it is a viable solution. Thank you.

Comment: My final solution ended up like this: `$a | % { "$_ : $(`"Hello $_ World`" | % { $_ -replace `"t`", `"T`" })" }` I think I'll just use nested foreach loops next time. :)

Comment: $a | % { "$_ : $("Hello $_ World" -replace "t", "T" )" }

Comment: in my situation, I wasn't actually doing a `-replace`, so I had to send the objects through another cmdlet. I guess I picked a poor example for demonstrating my question!

Comment: Try post your actual code (if you want)... maybe someone could find more performant one.